# Wiring up the Search Charm in Universal WinRT apps

Tags: search, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I haven't seen any examples of how to use the Search Charm in a Universal App.

Usually you wire up the Search Charm using:

`SearchPane.GetForCurrentView().QuerySubmitted += new TypedEventHandler<SearchPane, SearchPaneQuerySubmittedEventArgs>(OnQuerySubmitted);`

However that doesn't exist in the Shared App.xaml nor does the `Windows.ApplicationModel.Search` namespace.

Anyone seen how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to override the OnSearchActivated method in App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override async void OnSearchActivated(SearchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    await LoadApplicationAsync(args.PreviousExecutionState);
    // TODO: Handle search query in args            
}
```

LoadApplicationAsync contains the logic which can usually be found in the OnLaunched method.

See my sample project:

https://xp-dev.com/svn/mytoolkit/-%20Samples/SampleWindowsStoreApp/App.xaml.cs

https://xp-dev.com/svn/mytoolkit/-%20Samples/SampleWindowsStoreApp/Views/SearchSamplePage.xaml.cs

Comment: In my universal app the OnSearchActivated override is never triggered despite the manifest containing the Search declaration. Is it working for you? I'm not seeing anything in your implementation that would account for it.

Comment: OnSearchActivated is called in my sample app. Checkout https://xp-dev.com/svn/mytoolkit to test it... You have to open the search charm bar and select the application instead of everywhere...

Comment: Aha! It's a change in usability, using the Search charm from within an app no longer searches with your app as the context. It's less discoverable than before.